# Calculating enthalpy of a solid as a function of temperature in Molecular Dynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, material-science, simulations, molecular-dynamics

I would like to get the enthalpy as a function of temperature for BCC lithium at zero pressure.

I have performed a series of NVT simulations with 500 atoms using a Nose-Hoover thermostat at the corresponding equilibrium volumes (found using the volume average of NPT simulations) and calculated the enthalpy as $$ H = U + pV $$ which at zero pressure is just the total energy in the simulation. When I compare the result with experimental values from NIST referenced to the enthalpy at 0K, the enthalpy I get is significantly higher.

[image: plot of enthalpy vs temperature comparing MD and experimental enthalpy]

Things I've thought about:

1. It is not an offset so it's not like a constant contribution like zero point energy is missing and besides the referencing should fix that.
2. It is not a constant factor difference either and I think my units are fine.
3. The pressure is indeed 0 and fluctuates by about 0.005GPa which is tiny i.e. pV term fluctuation is less than 1meV/atom
4. The simulation is stable, it remains BCC the entire team as seen from Common Neighbor Analysis and the eye test.

My questions are:

1. Am I thinking about this wrong? Is there some reason why this is not a valid simulation protocol for getting the enthalpy of a solid?
2. Am I missing some term? It would have to be a decreasingfunction of temperature and any other contribution such as electronic enthalpy (from integrating electronic heat capacity) would make it worse by increasing the enthalpy
3. Am I just intepreting the experimental data wrong?